# Django rendering the HTML tags - How to eliminate them

Tags: django, django-templates

I am learning Django through the djangobook website and everything is going well, but the latest project I created (deals with templates) is showing all of the html tags in the web page - how do I eliminate them?

views.py:

```
def current_datetime(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    return render_to_response('current_datetime.html',{'current_date':now})
```

base.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My helpful timestamp site</h1>
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}
    <hr>
    <p>Thanks for visiting my site.</p>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

current_datetime.html:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}The current time{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<p>It is now {{ current_date }}.</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Unfortunately, instead of it displaying the page as it is supposed to, it is displaying all of the HTML tags with it.

Comment: You might try FireBug to see what Content-Type is being set in the response headers. It appears that it might be text/plain instead of text/html. Oh, and it might just be a typo in your question but your view is calling current_datetime.html  while you've listed your html file as current_date.html.

Comment: `render_to_response()` should create a `text/html` response by default.

Comment: So it's displaying something like `<title>The current time<title>` instead of just `The current time` ?

Answer (score 0):

in you urls.py

```
from mysite.views import current_datetime

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^time/$', current_datetime),
)
```

the template name must be equal to name in view current_datetime.html

in the terminal runserver this way

```
$ python manage.py runserver
```

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. All of the content is being transmitted correctly, it's just not being formatted correctly. (It still has the html tags)